# ipad dev - user direction (orientation) in mapkit

Tags: ipad, android-mapview

In the google maps app in iPad, when the user taps twice on the "locateMe" toolbar button, the map shows the user's direction (I mean orientation, whether facing east, west, south, or north). Is that available in the sdk 3.2? how would I do that with a mapview?

Answer (score 0):

alright i think i have an idea now. using cllocation and cllocationmanager may do what i want. there is a course property in cllocation returns the direction of the user.